# Sum by Dynamic Criteria List

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the function "SUMIFS" with "dynamic criteria".
See tables below.

In ***Table Overview*** Cell B2 I got the formula I try to figure out:
SUMIFS all Fruits (***Table Criteria***, Column A:A) in ***Table Data***.
And if there is a new product, e.g. apple, I would like to add it in the Table Criteria in A4 as "apple", and my Overview should add the amount of the apples to fruits.

Any ideas?

---

Table "Overview"

```
|_|        A        |        B        |    
|1| **Subject**        **Count**
|2| Fruits               10
|3| Vegtables            20
|4|
```

---

Table "Criteria"

```
|_|        A        |        B        |
|1| **Fruits**        **Vegtables**    
|2| Banana               Carrot        
|3| Kiwi                 Broccoli      
|4|
```

---

Table "Data"

```
|_|        A        |        B        |
|1| **Product**        **Count**    
|2| Banana               2        
|3| Kiwi                 3      
|4| Banana               5
|5| Carrot               5
|6| Broccoli            15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,INDEX($D$2:$E$2:INDEX(D:E,MATCH("zzz",INDEX(D:E,0,MATCH(G2,$D$1:$E$1,0))),MATCH(G2,$D$1:$E$1,0)),0,MATCH(G2,$D$1:$E$1,0))))
```

This is dynamic and will allow the addition of items to both input lists without the need to change the formula and still maintain the fewest iterations.  The SUMPRODUCT forces the SUMIFS criteria to iterate and while we can put the full column in it will iterate 1.04 million times and that would slow down the calc.

[image]

---

[image]

---

Now if they are true structured tables in Excel then it can be simplified because the table would limit the iterations:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Data[Count],Data[Product],INDEX(Criteria,0,MATCH([@Subject],Criteria[#Headers],0))))
```

[image]
[image]